# Android cloud notifications (FCM) not getting delivered

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

My application sometimes sends multiple notifications (Firebase cloud notifications) to the same Android device at the same time (or really, it sends one and then immediately sends the next one, etc).

Some of my users are complaining that only one of the notifications remains visible in their Notifications list when this happens.

Is this a known or expected behavior of Android? Is it deliberately hiding the other notifications? Is there some kind of minimum time I need to wait between notifications?

Frank